# In Unity, when I load a scene a second time, some objects don't show up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scenes: Menu and Game. I'm using C#.

When you die in the game, you get sent back to the menu with

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
```

There's a script with a GUIButton in the menu that, when clicked, loads the game with

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
```

What I want to happen is that when I click the button in the menu scene, it loads the game as if I just clicked the play button with the game scene open in the editor.

What instead happens is that it goes to the game scene, but some objects from the game scene appear to be missing. I'm not using DontDestroyOnLoad() anywhere.

Some objects from the scene do appear, but others don't. The weirdest thing is that there are some data fields on a script on the missing object that are referred to by some other scripts, and those give values that make sense.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on, or what I can do to get the desired result?

Comment: Are you using some Singletons by any chance?

Comment: @RyanSingh I don't know what a Singleton is. What is a Singleton, and how do I know if I'm using one?

Comment: @RyanSingh I've looked at a singleton tutorial since posting that... I have a couple objects with code that essentially does what a singleton does, and destroys itself if the instance variable is already loaded. I'll check if that's what's causing the objects to be destroyed...

EDIT: Yep, that's what was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that I was destroying one of my objects if it was not the first time that object was created, and I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 0):

are those static objects or dynamic? try to instantiate them in function which gets called on scene loaded.